# Pandas group reorder df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I already have this `df` with only three types of frame_code: `P20`, `P60` and `EV9`

```
      bus frame_code
0   U0032        EV9
1   U6762        P20
2   U1438        P20
3   U4623        P20
4   U1791        P20
..    ...        ...
88  U3804        P20
89  U4065        P20
90  U1035        P20
91  U0032        P20
92  U0032        P60
```

I need to group in the next `df`:

```
bus    P20  P60  EV9
U0032   2    1    1
U0762   1    0    0
.       .    .    .
```

I already tried using `group_by df = df[["bus", "frame_code"]].groupby(["frame_code"])`, however I couldn't achieve the proper result

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['bus'], df['frame_code'])`